# How to deploy Akka-HTTP project to Ubuntu Server?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, sbt-native-packager

I am using `sbt-native-packager`.

I added following code to build.sbt

```
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
```

I run this command in sbt shell

```
sbt stage
```

Universal folder has been created. 
And My project runs with this command in my Windows Computer. No any problem.

./target/universal/stage/bin/**MyProjectName.bat**

But I want to deploy on Ubuntu Server.
I could not run .bat command in Ubuntu. 
What do I need to do?

Comment: You can create a .deb file and deploy that. See https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formats/debian.html

Comment: I get an error like this -> `(debian:packageBin) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "fakeroot"`

Comment: @QwerSense can you try moving the `stage` folder to the server, or use the Universal packager and manually running the startup script in `bin`?

Comment: I would suggest you to use docker plugin of sbt-native-packager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the directory `./target/universal/stage/bin/` there will be an executable script with the same name with **no extension**.

On the linux server, run `./target/universal/stage/bin/MyProjectName` and the application will start. Make sure you copy everything in the `stage` folder, including `bin` and `lib`.

I highly recommend that you use one for the packagers. Universal packager will create a zip file that you can extract anywhere.